# How to get param value from java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, url-parameters

I'm trying to get param values passed to a Java Servlet but the string returned is not correct.  I'm storing the values in a Map and checking if the key exists.

```
Map params;
params = request.getParameterMap();

String id = params.get("id").toString();
String data = params.get("data").toString();

System.out.println("streaming" + data + " with id of " + id);
```

Yet if I call this servlet via `http://localhost:8080/Serv/stream/data?data=hereisdata&id=you` my output looks like this:

```
streaming[Ljava.lang.String;@5e2091d3 with id of [Ljava.lang.String;@36314ab8
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:  as the suggested answers are not working, I'm including the entire class as I'm likely messing something up within the class:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import Engine.Streamer;


public class AnalyzerController {

    private Map params;
    private String pathInfo;
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public AnalyzerController(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        this.params = request.getParameterMap();
        this.pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
    }

    public void processRequest()
    {
        System.out.println("procing with " + pathInfo);

        switch(pathInfo){
        case "/stream/data":
            if(params.containsKey("id") && params.containsKey("data")) processStream();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void processStream()
    {
        System.out.println("we are told to stream");
        String data = request.getParameter("data");
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        Streamer stream = new Streamer();   

        stream.streamInput(data, "Analyzer", id);           
    }
}
```

This line specifically is throwing the NPE:  `String data = request.getParameter("data");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the docs of the [`Request#getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29), it returns a `Map` of the type `Map<String, String[]>`. Therefore, you need to take out the first element from the value `String[]` array returned from the map.

```
String id = params.get("id")[0];
```

Ofcourse, you can avoid all this and directly get the parameters from the request objects using the [`Request#getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
```

*Edit:* Looking at your class code, it seems that the instance variable `request` is not initialized. Initialize that in the constructor like this:

```
public AnalyzerController(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    this.request = request; // Initialize your instance variable request which is used in the other methods.
    this.params = request.getParameterMap();
    this.pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
}
```

Comment: Why would you add a cast to `String[]` to a variable whose value is `String[]` already?

Comment: @WildBill - Ideally, if you've passed your parameters properly, neither of the 2 approaches given above shown give you a NPE.

Comment: I've put the entire class in an edit, in the event I am doing something that would cause such a failure.  The request is being submitted via a browser, which should be sufficient...

Comment: <embarrassed>that did it</embarrassed>

Answer (score 2):

You can get the required parameters instead of the whole map

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String data = request.getParameter("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
String data = ((String)params.get("data"));
```

Or directly from the Request.

```
String data = request.getParameter("data");
```

Comment: Why would you add a cast to `String` to a variable that will return a `String`?

Comment: My bad I forget getParameter return a String

Answer (score 1):

You can use request object plus it's method for to get data using`getParameter()` of you can use `getParameterValues()` if multiple data are from page.

```
String id = request.getParameter("id")
String data = request.getParameter("data")
```

why are you using `Map` ? 
Any special need of it or any reason ?

or you can use like this :

```
String id = params.get("id")[0];
```

Comment: Looking at the answers here it appears that Map is not the best way to store params, or at least retrieve them.  Putting them in a map lets me check if a particular key does exist however, and that check is done above (only provided small amount of code for the question).

Comment: ok but you can directly check `getPatemeter()` also that if data exist in that or not using `if` or specific function.

Comment: @WildBill using the `Map` approach is valid when there are several components with same name and you should retrieve all their values, e.g. `<input type="checkbox">`.

Comment: Yes WildBill, @LuiggiMendoza has good one, then you can use Map.

Comment: String id = params.get("id")[0]; throws a syntax error, saying `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object` and the getParameter is throwing a NullException...

Comment: Means data is not coming from Page, or there can be any naming problem in that. So first check name of control that are given in `getParameter()` method.